# Excel section of extended properties of a connection string to an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

Consider the following connection string to an Excel file :

```
public static string GetACEOleDB12ConnectionStringForImport(string filePath) => $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={filePath};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""";
```

In above, we have **Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0**

Now, what does that **Excel 12.0** exactly imply in comparison to **Excel 8.0**.

If we use Excel 12.0 instead of Excel 8.0, does that mean we are not covering Excel 8.0?

A documentation on this extended property would  be awesome. I did not find any reference documentaion on well-known links such as [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2013/)

Comment: isn't the excel 12.0 intended for documents with the xlsx extension?

Comment: It's to do with excel version. I think you use **`Excel 12.0`** for Excel 2007 and later. Any versions of Excel prior to Excel 2007, you would use **`Excel 8.0`**. To know which one to use, you first have to identify Excel version. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718490/finding-ms-office-revision-and-build-version-using-vba) to see how to do that

Comment: Are there any official documentation on this? I was not able to find any which is quite odd.